# jQuery check/uncheck radio button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have this code to check/uncheck a radio button onclick.

I know it is not good for the UI, but I need this.

```
$('#radioinstant').click(function() {     
  var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
  if(checked){ 
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }
  else{ 
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
  }
});
```

The above function is not working.

If I click on the button, nothing changes. It remain checked. Why? Where is the error? I am not a jQuery expert. I am on jQuery 1.3.2

Just to be clear `#radioinstant` is the ID of the radio button.

Comment: One should note that if you're also doing something with this radio based on its checked status, you may get misleading 'checked' values on onclick events. One solution is to assign on mousedown the value you are going to assign to it (the opposite of what it has) in a variable on the node like this.__rval and check for its existence in your onclick handler. If it exists, you know the value in it is correct, though the this.checked may be about to change.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If all you want to do is have a checkbox that checks, don't worry about doing it with JQuery.  That is default functionality of a checkbox on click.  However, if you want to do additional things, you can add them with JQuery.  Prior to jQuery 1.9, you can use use `$(this).attr('checked');` to get the value instead of `$(this).attr('checked', true);`, as the second will set the value.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP/1) is a fiddle demonstration that shows the default checkbox functionality vs. what you are doing with JQuery.

Note:  **After JQuery 1.6**, you should use `$(this).prop;` instead of `$(this).attr` in all three places (thanks @Whatevo for pointing this out and [see here for further details](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-)).

**UPDATE:**

<strike>Sorry, missed the requirement that it had to be a radio button.  You still may want to consider the checkbox, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP) is the updated code for the radio input version.  It works by setting the `previousValue` as an attribute on the checkbox, as I don't think `prop` is supported in 1.3.2.  You could also do this in a scoped variable, as some people don't like setting random attributes on fields.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/EtNXP) is the new example.</strike>

**UPDATE 2:**

As Josh pointed out, the previous solution only worked with one radio button.  Here's a function that makes a group of radios deselectable by their name, and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtNXP/1467/):

```
var makeRadiosDeselectableByName = function(name){
    $('input[name=' + name + ']').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('previousValue') == 'true'){
            $(this).attr('checked', false)
        } else {
            $('input[name=' + name + ']').attr('previousValue', false);
        }

        $(this).attr('previousValue', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });
};
```

Comment: My favorite method of checking the 'checked' state is to use $(this).is(':checked')

Comment: Noticed that .attr() doesn't work with a newer version of jQuery (1.9.1 in this case).  Change to $(this).prop("checked"); if you wnat to go this route.

Comment: Your radio button example doesn't work properly if you have more than one radio button (which is the whole purpose of using radio buttons).  Jurrie's answer is much closer to a solution.

Comment: @JoshStodola Thanks, that is fixed now.

Comment: var value = $('#radGroup').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

Answer (score 40):

I have expanded on the previous suggestions.
This works for me, with multiple radios coupled by the same name.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function()
{
  var previousValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');
  var name = $(this).attr('name');

  if (previousValue == 'checked')
  {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('previousValue', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("input[name="+name+"]:radio").attr('previousValue', false);
    $(this).attr('previousValue', 'checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed (thank you). I added a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/dan74/6KYVP/ - if a radio is checked by default, it's necessary to click twice to uncheck (I can live with that) but otherwise the radios behave as expected (an ability to uncheck)

Comment: Needs one correction...     $("input[name='" + name + "']:radio").attr('previousValue', false); ...note the single quotes around +name+ ... ' " + name + " '

Answer (score 13):

Instead of getting the checked value you are setting it with:

```
var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
```

To properly get it:

```
var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
```

### A working solution (with multiple radio buttons having different values):

```
// select radio buttons group (same name)
var radioButtons = $("input[type='radio'][name='rr']");
// save initial ckecked states
var radioStates = {};
$.each(radioButtons, function(index, rd) {
    radioStates[rd.value] = $(rd).is(':checked');
});

// handle click event
radioButtons.click(function() {
    
    // check/unchek radio button
    var val = $(this).val();  
    $(this).prop('checked', (radioStates[val] = !radioStates[val]));    
    
    // update other buttons checked state
    $.each(radioButtons, function(index, rd) {
        if(rd.value !== val) {
            radioStates[rd.value] = false; 
        }
    });
});
```

***P.S.:*** `$().attr` should be used instead of `$().prop` for jquery < 1.6

#### Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Se9DL/729/)

Comment: yes it's not working because whenever you click you're setting it's state to `checked=true` (a click is a check for a radio button)

Comment: you have to store it's state in a global variable and check on that. See my edit.

Comment: Why would you have a "working solution" with just one radio button?  There is no point to using ONE radio button there will always be multiple choices...

Comment: @JoshStodola, no need to be mad, the question was about one single radio button. But, you are right about having a solution for multiple radio buttons. Answer updated.

Answer (score 12):

Best and shortest solution. It will work for any group of radios (with the same name).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio:checked").data("chk",true);
    $("input:radio").click(function(){
        $("input[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']:radio").not(this).removeData("chk");
        $(this).data("chk",!$(this).data("chk"));
        $(this).prop("checked",$(this).data("chk"));
        $(this).button('refresh'); // in case you change the radio elements dynamically
    });
});
```

More information, [here](http://slavik.meltser.info/make-the-radio-buttons-behave-like-single-choice-checkboxes/).

Enjoy.

Comment: works but I had to refresh the buttons for it to update the buttons... added this at the end
` $(this).button('refresh');`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the problem:  If you have more than one radio button, and one of them is clicked, there is no way to deselect all of them.  What is needed is a "none or only one" selector, so checkboxes would not be appropriate.  You could have a "clear" button or something like that to deselect all, but it would be nice to just click the selected radio button to deselect it and go back to the "none" state, so you don't clutter your UI with an extra control.

The problem with using a click handler is that by the time it is called, the radio button is already checked.  You don't know if this is the initial click or a second click on an already checked radio button.  So I'm using two event handlers, mousedown to set the previous state, then the click handler as used above:

```
$("input[name=myRadioGroup]").mousedown(function () 
{
    $(this).attr('previous-value', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

$("input[name=myRadioGroup]").click(function () 
{
    var previousValue = $(this).attr('previous-value');

    if (previousValue == 'true')
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: at last, the only solution that correctly address the problem: the radio IS checked already when click event happens, making all those solution depending on the checked state absolutely useless

Answer (score 2):

`toggleAttr()` is provided by [this very nice and tiny plugin](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/298591).

#### Sample code

```
$('#my_radio').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleAttr('checked');
});

/**
 * toggleAttr Plugin
 */
jQuery.fn.toggleAttr = function(attr) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr(attr) ? $this.removeAttr(attr) : $this.attr(attr, attr);
    });
};
```

#### Even more fun, [demo](http://jsbin.com/hajeq/edit)

You can use place your radio button inside label or button tags and do some nice things.

Answer (score 2):

```js
        $(document).on("click", "input[type='radio']", function(e) {
            var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
            if(!checked){
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="radio" /> <label for="radio">Radio</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

**-- EDIT --**

It sure looks like your code is forcing a radio input to behave like a checkbox input.  You might think about just using a checkbox input without the need for jQuery.  However, if you want to force, like @manji said, you need to store the value outside the click handler and then set it on each click to the opposite of what it is at that time.  @manji's answer is correct, I would just add that you should cache jQuery objects instead of re-querying the DOM:

```
var $radio = $("#radioinstant"),
    isChecked = $radio.attr("checked");

$radio.click(function() {

    isChecked = !isChecked;
    $(this).attr("checked", isChecked);

});
```

Comment: This will work only for the first time. But if the user then decide to check it again, it won't work. Users may change their decision while they are doing things. How can I say onclick to check it if it is unchecked and to uncheck it if it is checked EVERYtime? Thank you

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to force a radio input to act like a checkbox input?

Answer (score 1):

Improved version of answer from Jurrie

```
$('#myRadio').off('click').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).data('checked')) {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).data('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(this).data('checked', true);
  }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/7epba8x1/)

Answer (score 1):

Having tested some of the above solutions which did not work for me 100%, I decided to create my own. It creates new click listeners after a radio button is clicked:

```
/**
 * Radio select toggler
 * enables radio buttons to be toggled when clicked
 * Created by Michal on 09/05/2016.
 */

var radios = $('input[type=radio]');

/**
 * Adds click listeners to all checkboxes to unselect checkbox if it was checked already
 */
function updateCheckboxes() {
    radios.unbind('click');
    radios.filter(':checked').click(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    radios.click(function () {
        updateCheckboxes();
    });
}

updateCheckboxes();
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio:checked").data("chk",true);

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
    $("input[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']:radio").not(this).removeData("chk");

    $(this).data("chk",!$(this).data("chk"));

    $(this).prop("checked",$(this).data("chk"));
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

DiegoP,

I was having the same trouble, until I realized that the check on the box doesnt go off until the attribute is removed. That means even if checked value is made false, it will remain there.

Hence use the removeAttr() function and remove the checked attrib and it WILL DEFINITELY WORK.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still up for more answers i have found that this works with all radio buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
                    var allRadios = $('input[type=radio]')
                    var radioChecked;

                    var setCurrent = 
                                    function(e) {
                                        var obj = e.target;

                                        radioChecked = $(obj).attr('checked');
                                 }

                    var setCheck = 
                                function(e) {

                                    if (e.type == 'keypress' && e.charCode != 32) {
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    var obj = e.target;

                         if (radioChecked) {
                         $(obj).attr('checked', false);
                         } else {
                         $(obj).attr('checked', true);
                         }
                             }    

                    $.each(allRadios, function(i, val){        
                         var label = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr("id") + ']');

                     $(this).bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
                            setCurrent(e);
                        });

                        label.bind('mousedown keydown', function(e){
                            e.target = $('#' + $(this).attr("for"));
                            setCurrent(e);
                        });

                     $(this).bind('click', function(e){
                            setCheck(e);    
                        });

                    });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will add a check/unchecked to all radiobuttons

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(':radio').click(function()
{
if ((jQuery(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') && (jQuery(this).attr('class') == 'checked'))
{   
    jQuery(this).attr('class','unchecked');
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('checked');
} else {
jQuery(this).attr('class','checked');
}//or any element you want

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I took https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575528/80353 and adapted it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('body').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
            changeCheckedAttributes($(this));
        });
        function changeCheckedAttributes(elt) {
            $("input[name='"+$(elt).attr("name")+"']:radio").not($(elt)).removeData("chk");
            $("input[name='"+$(elt).attr("name")+"']:radio").not($(elt)).removeAttr("checked");
            $("input[name='"+$(elt).attr("name")+"']:radio").not($(elt)).prop("checked", false);
            $(elt).data("chk",!$(elt).data("chk"));
            $(elt).prop("checked", true);
            $(elt).attr("checked", $(elt).data("chk"));
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
$('input[type="radio"].toggle').click(function () {
    var $rb = $(this);

    if ($rb.val() === 'on') {
        $rb.val('off');
        this.checked = false;
    }
    else {
        $rb.val('on');
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type="radio" class="toggle" value="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a related but different scenario. Following is what I am doing:

Note: Code to select/unselect all radio buttons of class 'containerRadio' when the main radio button is selected.

**CODE**

```
        $('#selectAllWorkLot').click (function ()
        {

              var previousValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');

              if (previousValue == 'checked')
              {
                resetRadioButtonForSelectAll();

                //Unselect All
                unSelectAllContainerRadioButtons();
              }
              else
              {
                $(this).attr('previousValue', 'checked');

                //Select All
                selectAllContainerRadioButtons();
              }
        });


        function resetRadioButtonForSelectAll()
        {
            $('#selectAllWorkLot').removeAttr('checked');
            $('#selectAllWorkLot').attr('previousValue', false);
            //$('#selectAllWorkLot').prop('checked', false);
        }


        function selectAllContainerRadioButtons()
        {
            $('.containerRadio').prop('checked', true);
        }

        function unSelectAllContainerRadioButtons()
        {
            $('.containerRadio').prop('checked', false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a related problem - I had to open a dialog box from dropdown based on selection from dropdown I will showing one or two radio button. Only one radio button can be activated at a time.

- Option 1 will show two radio button with 1st radio selected
- Option 2 will show second radio button and selected.

The script works some time some time it injects the checked but checkbox still unchecked

I went to jQuery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), seems like `jquery .prop() .attr()` has some complication with radio buttons while using attr or prop. So What I did instead is trigger the click on the radio button based on Select value.

That resolve the need of using attr or prop or using on off lengthy code.

```
myForm = $("#myForm");

if (argument === 'multiple') {
            myForm.find('#radio1').parent('li').hide();
            myForm.find('#radio2').trigger('click');
    }
    else{
        myForm.find('#radio1').trigger('click');
         myForm.find('#radio1').parent('li').show();
    }
```

Not sure if this is best practice but it - Works like charm

Answer (score 0):

here is simple solution i hope it will help you. here's a simple example to improve answer.

```
$('[type="radio"]').click(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('checked')) {

                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).prop('checked',false);

            } else {

                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');

            }
        });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SajidSidhu/v9an7f1m/)
sorry for too late.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This last solution is the one that worked for me. I had problem with Undefined and object object or always returning false then always returning true but this solution that works when checking and un-checking.

This code shows fields when clicked and hides fields when un-checked :

```
$("#new_blah").click(function(){
   if ($(this).attr('checked')) {

            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    var radioValue = $(this).prop('checked',false);
    // alert("Your are a rb inside 1- " + radioValue);
    // hide the fields is the  radio button is no     
    $("#new_blah1").closest("tr").hide();
    $("#new_blah2").closest("tr").hide();

    } 
    else {

    var radioValue =  $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    // alert("Your are a rb inside 2 - " + radioValue);
    // show the fields   when radio button is set to  yes
    $("#new_blah1").closest("tr").show();
    $("#new_blah2").closest("tr").show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions I tried from this question did not work for me. Of the answers that worked partially, I still found that I had to click the previously unchecked radio button twice just to get it checked again. I'm currently using jQuery 3+.

After messing around with trying to get this to work using data attributes or other attributes, I finally figured out the solution by using a class instead.

For your checked radio input, give it the class `checked` e.g.:

```
<input type="radio" name="likes_cats" value="Meow" class="checked" checked>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    }
    else {
        $('input[name="'+name+'"]').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use on click and only check if radio is checked and then deselect, you will never get the radio checked. So maybe easiest is to use classnames like this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('alreadyChecked')) {//it is already checked
        $('.myRadios').removeClass('alreadyChecked');//remove from all radios
        $(this).prop('checked', false);//deselect this
    }
    else {
        $('.myRadios').removeClass('alreadyChecked');//remove from all
        $(this).addClass('alreadyChecked');//add to only this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution. For both Radio and Checkboxes.

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked')){
        $( this ).attr( 'checked', false);
    } else {
        $( this ).attr( 'checked', true);
    }
});
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $("input[name="+name+"]:radio").attr('checked', false);
    $( this ).attr( 'checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest way. I tested it on Chrome and MS Edge.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:radio', function () {
    var check = $(this).attr('checked')
    if (check) $(this).removeAttr('checked').prop('checked',false)
    else $(this).attr('checked', true).prop('checked',true)
})
```

This piece of code also works on **AJAX loaded** contents.

Alternatively, You can also use

```
$(document).on('click mousedown', 'input:radio', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) $(this).prop('checked', false)
    else $(this).prop('checked', true)
})
```

This would work better without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers in this thread were helpful for me, and I thought I'd share an updated answer using jQuery and HTML 5:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadioGroupName" value="true" checked="false" data-checked-before="false"/>
<input type="radio" name="myRadioGroupName" value="false" checked="false" data-checked-before="false"/>

$(function () {
    // Allows us to easily uncheck radio buttons.
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function (e) {
        var htmlName = $(this).attr('name');
        var radio = $("input[name='" + htmlName + "'][value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
        // Since onclick() and preventDefault() work differently for radio buttons, we
        // have to wait until after all the values have been set,
        // and then set them to what we want.
        setTimeout(function () {
            // $(radio).is(":checked") will always return true, so we have to
            // set our own HTML property.
            if ($(radio).attr('data-checked-before') == 'true') {
                $(radio).prop("checked", false);
            }
            ClearCheckedBefore(htmlName);
            // Save the state for the next time we look at it.
            $(radio).attr('data-checked-before', $(radio).is(':checked').toString());
        }, 5);
    });
});

// Marks all data-checked-before attributes to false, so the
// if-statements in the setTimeout function don't get confused.
function ClearCheckedBefore(htmlName) {
    $("input[name='" + htmlName + "']").each(function (index, value) {
        $(value).attr('data-checked-before', 'false');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the best and way .finally worked for me

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type=radio]", function (e) {
        var checked=$(this).hasAttr("checked");
        if(checked) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
        else {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
```