# How to uncheck (unclick) a checked radio button widget in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: firefox, jquery-mobile, radio-button, checked

I have a group of radio buttons in a jQuery Mobile application. I would like to "uncheck" a checked radio button when I click on it again, so none of the buttons in the group are highlighted and the "serialize" function called on the form doesn't return any value for that radio group. I can do that for desktops with such code:

```
$('form').on('click', 'div:has(>.ui-radio-on)', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked',false).checkboxradio('refresh');
})
```

You can test it at http://jsfiddle.net/xqqauoq3/.

Unfortunately it doesn't work on Firefox for Android nor Chrome for Android.

How to implement that functionality so it works on both mobile and desktop?

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: This works on Chrome for mobile (i dont use firefox so test it and see) -- demo  http://jsfiddle.net/r1r7dura/  -- taken from here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191621/jquery-check-uncheck-radio-button-onclick

Comment: @Tasos Your code works also in Firefox for Android, but it stops working when I attach the handler to the form with $('form').on('click', 'input[type=radio]', unclick_func) -- demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0bro6x10/  Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: You cant do it that way as the click wont reach the radio buttons. you need (form input[type='radio']) -- demo http://jsfiddle.net/pqbaas3L/

Comment: @Tasos Why it won't reach the radios? I'm adding new radio buttons dynamically; do I have to attach the handler manually for each one?