# Radio button with accordion, radio button selected doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am creating a radio buttons which pressed will open up an accordion with details. I have figured out the creation of the accordion. But the selected/checked radio doesn't change when I press the other buttons, but their accordion does open up but the selection remains as the first one. I have taken the first one as the default selection initially.

When I didn't implement the accordion, I was able to change selections between the radio buttons.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
</script>
 <div class="container-fluid bg-default" id="rides">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ">
            <fieldset >
                <div id = "accordion">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="ride_id" id="radio1" value="1" checked = "checked">
                        <label class="btn-list btn-block btn-xl" for="radio1">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Los Angeles </span>
                            <span class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i></span>
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Las Vegas</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>Details of route 1</div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="ride_id" id="radio2" value="2">
                        <label class="btn-list btn-block btn-xl" for="radio2">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Los Angeles</span>
                            <span class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i></span>
                            <span class="col-sm-5">San Francisco</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>Details of route 2</div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="ride_id" id="radio3" value="3">
                        <label class="btn-list btn-block btn-xl" for="radio3">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Los Angeles</span>
                            <span class="col-sm-2"><i class="fa fa-arrows-h"></i> </span>
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Sacramento</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>Details of route 3</div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <a onclick="" href='#register' class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block page-scroll">Book</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does seem to be that by attaching the accordion click events are no longer reaching the radio buttons. You can get around this by saving the radio button when its clicked and checking it when the animation is over.

```
$(function() {
    var inputClicked;
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        beforeActivate: function(evt, ui){
            inputClicked = $('input', evt.currentTarget)
            //$('input', evt.currentTarget).prop("checked", "checked");
        },
        activate: function(evt, ui){
           inputClicked.prop("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
 });
```

Running example at http://jsfiddle.net/hw4vx3cy/1/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change your jquery. Perform the following steps:

1. First, know which radio button is clicked.
   Declare a same class class ="radio_class" for all your radio buttons, and use .change function to detect for changes.
2. Uncheck all radio buttons (or uncheck previously checked radio button)
3. Check the clicked radio button and run accordion.

   Visit the following link:
   [jQuery check/uncheck radio button onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191621/jquery-check-uncheck-radio-button-onclick)
   Refer to the answer given by Jurrie.