# .prop('checked', false) doesn't uncheck radio button after clicking on a label

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".label").click(function(){
    var id = $("#uncheck");
    var value = id.val();
    if(value == 'unchecked'){
      id.val('checked');
    } else {
      id.val('unchecked');
      id.prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='label' for='uncheck'>uncheck</label>
<input class='input' type='radio' id='uncheck' value='unchecked'>
```

I keep trying to uncheck the radio button but it won't work,

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery

Comment: @turmuka isn't in my code `id.prop('checked', false);` is same as `$('#uncheck').prop("checked", flase)`?

Comment: Having a label event handler do the opposite of what it would normally do is semantically incorrect. You might want to reconsider, since most people expect clicking text adjacent to a form element to toggle or focus its state. What you're doing here will just confuse a lot of users.

Comment: What Patrick said, plus you may want to use a checkbox to signify on/off. Radios are normally for choosing "one out of many".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191621/jquery-check-uncheck-radio-button-onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the default action (label is setting the radio back). You can do it by returning `false` from your event handler:

```js
$(".label").click(function(){
    var id = $("#uncheck");
    if(!!id.prop('checked')) {
      id.prop('checked', false);
      return false;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='label' for='uncheck'>uncheck</label>
<input class='input' type='radio' id='uncheck' value='unchecked'>
```

Or using [`event.preventDefault()` method](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```js
$(".label").click(function(e){
    var id = $("#uncheck");
    var value = id.val();
    if(value == 'unchecked'){
      id.val('checked');
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      id.val('unchecked');
      id.prop('checked', false);
    }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='label' for='uncheck'>uncheck</label>
<input class='input' type='radio' id='uncheck' value='unchecked'>
```